# rails upgrade undefined method default url options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just upgraded my app to rails 4 from rails 3 and some of my view pages dont show. The error comes from this type of link_for -

```
user.bets.map { |bet| link_for(bet) }
```

and error-

```
undefined local variable or method 'default_url_options' for #ActionView::Base...
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post more details about your view, controller, model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 4 introduces this logic: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L93

Where default_url_options becomes a mattr_writer, rather than a matter_reader. You will have to define it yourself in a suitable space.

Most apps will have a config.domain_name defined in the env files, which is evaluated to a const like DOMAIN_NAME through constants.rb.

So default_url_options should be defined in application_helper:

```
def default_url_options
  { host: DOMAIN_NAME }
end
```